# Ordering a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I do not understand why this code does not return the list ordered:

```
A = {2:'a', 1: 'b', 3:'c'} 

R = list(a.keys()).sort()
```

In fact it does not return anything. I know I could do it in other ways like `sorted(a.keys)`.

Thanks

Comment: Type `help(list(a.keys()).sort)` you'll see why. Do not call it, just use the `help` function on the method.

Comment: `sort()` sorts the array in place and returns `None`. `sorted()` returns a new array.

Comment: `list.sort` returns `None`. It *does* sort the list, but you never maintain a reference to that list, so it is discarded.

Comment: Assign the keys to `R`, then use `R.sort()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: All clear. Thank you. Do you think I should delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort()` does in-place changes to the list. What you can do is create a variable to store the keys and then sort it.

```
R = list(a.keys())
R.sort()
```

<s>Use `R = sorted(list(a.keys()))` instead, as `sort()` serve as an in-place function</s>

Comment: He said he knows he can use `sorted()`.